# Spring boot TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, transactions, spring-data

I am receiving a `TransactionRequiredException` when performing an update operation using `@Query` in an application that interacts with multiple databases.

**Service**

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.intecon.wittureexportsync.entity.Tfeft000HeaderTteft002SyncTracker;
import com.intecon.wittureexportsync.entity.eintecon.Tfeft000Header;
import com.intecon.wittureexportsync.repository.baan.Ttfeft002330Repository;
import com.intecon.wittureexportsync.repository.eintecon.Tfeft000HeaderRepository;
import com.intecon.wittureexportsync.repository.einteconjobs.Tfeft000HeaderTteft002SyncTrackerRepository;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;


import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Slf4j
@Service
public class SyncTrackerService {

    private final Tfeft000HeaderTteft002SyncTrackerRepository trackerRepository;
    private final Tfeft000HeaderRepository tfeft000HeaderRepository;
    private final Ttfeft002330Repository ttfeft002330Repository;
    public static final String SYNC_PENDING = "SYNC_PENDING";
    public static final String CANCELED = "CANCELED";
    public static final String SUCCESSFUL = "SUCCESSFUL";

    public SyncTrackerService(Tfeft000HeaderTteft002SyncTrackerRepository trackerRepository,
            Tfeft000HeaderRepository tfeft000HeaderRepository, Ttfeft002330Repository ttfeft002330Repository) {
        this.trackerRepository = trackerRepository;
        this.tfeft000HeaderRepository = tfeft000HeaderRepository;
        this.ttfeft002330Repository = ttfeft002330Repository;
    }

public void updateInvoiceIdsInTtfeft002330() {

        List<Tfeft000HeaderTteft002SyncTracker> trackers = trackerRepository
                .findBySyncStatusAndTrialLessThan(SYNC_PENDING, 4);
        List<Tfeft000HeaderTteft002SyncTracker> trackersToUpdate = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Tfeft000HeaderTteft002SyncTracker tracker : trackers) {
            try {

                String invoiceId = tracker.getInvoiceId(); 
                String tparmValue = tracker.getSummaryData().trim();
                log.info(tparmValue + ",");
                int affectedRows = ttfeft002330Repository.updateInvoiceIdByTparm(invoiceId, tparmValue.trim());
                if (affectedRows > 0) {
                    tracker.setSyncStatus(SUCCESSFUL);
                } else {
                    log.info("ttfeft002330 tablosunda işlem yapılamadı");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("ttfeft002330 tablosu güncelenirken hata oluştu --> " + e);
                tracker.setError(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                trackersToUpdate.add(tracker);
            }

        }
        try {
            if (!trackersToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                trackerRepository.saveAll(trackersToUpdate);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("tracker güncellerken hata oldu -->" + e);
        }
    }
```

**Repository**

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.intecon.wittureexportsync.entity.baan.Ttfeft002330;

@Repository
@Transactional("baanTransactionManager")
public interface Ttfeft002330Repository extends JpaRepository<Ttfeft002330, String>{
    List<Ttfeft002330> findTop10ByOrderByTidimDesc();
    List<Ttfeft002330> findByTparm(String tparmValue);
    
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE Ttfeft002330 t SET t.tpar1 = :invoiceId WHERE t.tparm = :tparm AND t.tpar1 IS NULL")
    int updateInvoiceIdByTparm(@Param("invoiceId") String invoiceId, @Param("tparm") String tparm);
}
```

**Entity**

```java
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;


@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "TTFEFT002330", schema = "BAAN")
public class Ttfeft002330 {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "T$IDIM", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String tidim;

    @Column(name = "T$FTYP", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String tftyp;

    @Column(name = "T$PROC", nullable = false)
    private Integer tproc;

    @Column(name = "T$MESS", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String tmess;

    @Column(name = "T$PAR1", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String tpar1;

    @Column(name = "T$PAR2", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String tpar2;

    @Column(name = "T$PAR3", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String tpar3;

    @Column(name = "T$PARM", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String tparm;

}
```

**BaanDbConfig**

```java
  package com.intecon.wittureexportsync.configs;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;


import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

import com.intecon.wittureexportsync.utils.JpaProperties;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.intecon.wittureexportsync.repository.einteconjobs",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "einteconjobsEntityManagerFactory", 
        transactionManagerRef = "einteconjobsTransactionManager")
public class DbConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.mysql.einteconjobs")
    DataSource einteconJobsDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean einteconjobsEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
         Map<String, String> jpaProperties = new HashMap<>();
         jpaProperties.put(JpaProperties.HIBERNATE_DIALECT, JpaProperties.MYSQL_DIALECT);
        
         return builder.dataSource(einteconJobsDataSource())
                .packages("com.intecon.wittureexportsync.entity")
                .persistenceUnit("einteconjobsPU")
                .properties(jpaProperties)
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Primary
    PlatformTransactionManager einteconjobsTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

I placed the `@Transactional` annotation on the `updateInvoiceIdByTparm` method, but the problem was not resolved. I then positioned it on top of the service, but still no improvement. However, the `findTop10ByOrderByTidimDesc` method is working fine.

Comment: Is your method `updateInvoiceIdsInTtfeft002330` in a class annotated `@Service` or `@Component` and this service or component well injected either by an `@Autowired` or by constructor? Can you show us how the class carrying the `updateInvoiceIdsInTtfeft002330` method is defined, with it's annotations?